# Getting getCurrentID from Menu?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ektron

> I have cms flex menu control as web user control.

```
<CMS:FlexMenu ID="menu_box"   CacheInterval="0" DisplayXslt="~XMLFiles/Menu.xslt" runat="server" />
```

> In workarea i created ektron submenu. Now in code behind i need to getcurrentID to get current page. This is my first encounter with ektron controls so anyone knows how to get it ?
>   Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to get the currently selected item in the flex menu, or get the Content / Page ID (i.e., the CMS object ID)?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to refer to the control on the page you would use

```
menu_box.[property];
menu_box.ID;
```

If you want to reference it in JavaScript you would use

```
ClientID + "_menu_box";
```

If you need to get that back to the page you can add a JavaScript function that does something like this:

```
JS.RegisterJSBlock(this, "alert('" + ClientID + "_menu_box');", "JavaScriptCodeBlock");
```